# What does CountImages() actually do?

Tags: dm-script

The command CountImages() has unexpected behaviors.  I found it can return a number > 0 even if there is no image in sight anywhere. I have also noticed that it can count all displayed images twice. Sometimes, it does what it seems to suggest at first glance:  count all the (displayed) images.  Greatly appreciate any explanation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CountImages()` command counts *all* `image` objects currently held in memory *except* so called utility images. This includes all shown images as well as images from other work spaces, images currently not shown (f.e. not shown images of a compound document, or those *hidden* by the according command).

The command `CountAllImages()` includes utility images as well.

These are old commands from the early days of DigitalMicrograph when things were a lot simpler. I would not recommend using it in scripts anymore. However, an example of use would be

```c
ClearResults()
result("\n Count Images:"+CountImages())
result("\n Count All Images:"+CountAllImages())

image img := FirstImage()
number count = 0
while(img.ImageIsValid())
{
    count++
    result("\n Image #"+Format(count,"%03d")+" = ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:"+img.ImageGetName())
    try{ img := NextImage(img); }
    catch{ img := NULL; break;}
}
Result("\n DONE")
```

A better way to count things on a workspace is to count `ImageDocuments` which are the containers of one or more images and access data that way, but this might be a separate question.

In any case, I'm attaching a script that counts and lists various things for clarity:

```c
number numImages = CountImages()                // Shown or not shown, all workspaces. Excludes utility imgages
number numImages_all = CountAllImages()         // Shown or not shown, all workspaces. Includes utility imgages

number numIDocs = CountImageDocuments()                     // Shown on current workspaces. 
number numIDocs_all = CountImageDocumentsOfAllWorkSpaces()  // Shown or not shown, any workspace. 

ClearResults()
Result("\n Count Images    : " + numImages ) 
Result("\n Count ALL Images: " + numImages_all )
Result("\n Count Image Documents: " + numIDocs ) 
Result("\n Count Image Documents (all Works spaces): " + numIDocs_all ) 

// Iterate over all shown Images on current workspace
Result("\n\n*****\nImage Documents on current Workspace:")
for( number i = 0; i<numIDocs; i++ )
{
    ImageDocument doc = GetImageDocument(i)
    Result("\n\t Doc ID = " + doc.ImageDocumentGetID() + " '" + doc.ImageDocumentGetName() + "'")
    number numImg = doc.ImageDocumentCountImages()
    for( number j = 0; j<numImg; j++ )
    {
        image img := doc.ImageDocumentGetImage(j)
        Result("\n\t\t Img ID = " + img.ImageGetID() + " ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:'" + img.ImageGetName() + "'")       
    }   
}

// Iterate over all Images via ImageDocuments
Result("\n\n*****\nImage Documents (any Workspace):")
for( number i = 0; i<numIDocs_all; i++ )
{
    ImageDocument doc = GetImageDocumentOfAllWorkspaces(i)
    Result("\n\t Doc ID = " + doc.ImageDocumentGetID() + " '" + doc.ImageDocumentGetName() + "'")
    Result("\t Workspace ID = "+doc.ImageDocumentGetWorkspace())
    number numImg = doc.ImageDocumentCountImages()
    for( number j = 0; j<numImg; j++ )
    {
        image img := doc.ImageDocumentGetImage(j)
        Result("\n\t\t Img ID = " + img.ImageGetID() + " ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:'" + img.ImageGetName() + "'")       
    }   
}

// Iterate over all Images, excluding not shown utility images
Result("\n\n*****\nAll Images (except utility):")
for( number i = 0; i<numImages; i++ )
{
    image img := FindImageByIndex(i)
    if (img.ImageIsValid()) 
        Result("\n\t\t Img ID = " + img.ImageGetID() + " ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:'" + img.ImageGetName() + "'")       
}

// Iterate over all Images, including not shown utility images
Result("\n\n*****\nAbsolutely All Images:")
for( number i = 0; i<numImages_all; i++ )
{
    image img := FindImageByIndex(i)
    if (img.ImageIsValid()) 
        Result("\n\t\t Img ID = " + img.ImageGetID() + " ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"]:'" + img.ImageGetName() + "'")       
}
```